# Scrolling Table CSS

Tags: css, scroll, css-tables

I'm playing around with a scrolling table. Right now I have two different JSfiddles, and both have something wrong with the css but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

The 1st JSFiddle looks ok except I don't want it to scroll horizontally, I want the thead and body to fit inside the full width of the div tag.

```
.table-scroll1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #1e73be;
}
table-scroll1.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
```

[JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/McKeeper44/Ljt1bt90/)

The 2nd JSFiddle, the columns in the body aren't lining up with the header.

```
table tbody, table thead {
  display: block;
}

table body {
   overflow:auto;
   height: 600px;
}
```

[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/McKeeper44/o0g9drmz/2/)

Any help would be much appreciated.